# Ng-model on Select-tag returns null/undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to save a post that a user creates, I keep getting null on the username so the back-end crashes.

The HTML:

```
<select name="user" class="input">
   <option value="" ng-model="post.Username" ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

The controller:

```
var NewPostController = function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, Post) {
    $scope.post = new Post();
    $scope.save = function () {
        Post.save($scope.post, function () {
            console.log($scope.post);
            $location.path('/');
        });
}
```

This is my DAL-part:

```
public void AddPost(Post post)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=XXX;User Id=XXX;Password=XXX;");
        string sql = "INSERT INTO Post (Title, Comment, Date, Imagelink, Username) VALUES(@Title, @Comment, @Date, @Imagelink, @Username)";
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", post.Title);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", post.Comment);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", "2015");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imagelink", post.ImageLink);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", post.Username);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put ng-model on select. Also, you need selected value to be username (user.Name).

Try this:

```
<select name="user" class="input" ng-model="post.Username">
 <option value="{{user.Name}}" ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Now the dropdown is totally blank :P

Comment: Opss! My mistake. I've forgot  curly braces. Please check my update to the answer.